# php: Always losing item #1 in ArrayIterator with using ArrayIterator::offsetUnset for a current element in loop

Tags: php, arrayiterator

I'm always losing second item (#1) in forearh of ArrayIterator and removing each element.

```
$cnt = 0;
$a = new ArrayIterator();
$a->append(++$cnt);
$a->append(++$cnt);
$a->append(++$cnt);
$a->append(++$cnt);
$a->append(++$cnt);

foreach ($a as $i => $item) {
    print_r("$i => $item".PHP_EOL);
    $a->offsetUnset($i);
}
print_r('count: '.$a->count().PHP_EOL);

foreach ($a as $i => $item) {
    print_r("lost! $i => $item".PHP_EOL);
}
```

Output:

```
0 => 1
2 => 3
3 => 4
4 => 5
count: 1
lost! 1 => 2
```

How it's possible? oO

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.5.37 (cli) (built: Jun 22 2016 16:14:46)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations! You have found a [documented bug in ArrayIterator](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55157)

Extract:

> ArrayIterator always skips the second element in the array when calling 
>   offsetUnset(); on it while looping through.
>
> Using the key from iterator and unsetting in the actual ArrayObject works as 
>   expected.

Comment: Well, thanks for spotting the bug. I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Seem, there is the only to exhaust `ArrayIterator` with method `offsetUnset`.
That's using `do..while`:

```
do {
    print_r("{$a->key()} => {$a->current()}".PHP_EOL);
    $a->offsetUnset($a->key());
} while ($a->count());
print_r('count: '.$a->count() . PHP_EOL);
```

Output:

```
0 => 1
1 => 2
2 => 3
3 => 4
4 => 5
count: 0
```